# Can users modify the redux state if devTools set to false?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I understand the state can be modified by the client by using the re dispatching a certain reducer with a different payload, but what if they can not see the state.
Will it still be possible for a user to edit the state if devTools is set to false?

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from './userSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    userData: userReducer
  },
  devTools: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to prevent state modification?

If it's for security reasons, you should assume that any code running on the client can be modified at will by the user. They could download your JS or just edit it directly in the browser, modifying it however they see fit, re-enabling `devTools` or doing anything else. Security should be handled by the server, not the client.

It won't be as easy to modify the state without that flag set, though.